# Java large file download/upload over HTTP - OutOfMemoryError on client side?

Tags: java, http, memory, io, file-transfer

I need to provide a way to download large files.

My implementation works, but it may fail with `OutOfMemoryError` on the client side - sometimes setting more heap helps, sometimes it does not.

I works perfectly fine on my machine (32GB RAM), but frequently fails on machines that have ~6GB.

My files are close to 2GB.

What should modify to provide a failsafe download method? 
I guess an error occurrs on `entity.writeTo(...);`.
I also guess it stores entire file in memory, which it should not. How do I write all the data to disk and ensure that there are no large memory buffers?

Would it help if I read from `InputStream` in chunks of `byte[1024]`?

The same question applies to the server. I am using `Files.copy(...)` to transfer the data because I read somewhere that it calls OS's API function and actual disk I/O occur.

**Client:**

```
public boolean requestUpdateDownload(String filePath)
{
    Path path = Paths.get(filePath).toAbsolutePath();
    File file = path.toFile();
    String url = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/download";

    System.out.println("Downloading update file from " + url);

    try
    {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        try
        {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            long expectedSize = entity.getContentLength();

            if (entity != null)
            {
                try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file))
                {
                    entity.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
                }
            }

            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            long realSize = file.length();

            if (expectedSize == realSize)
            {
                System.out.println("Received update file: " + realSize + " bytes total.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Update file incomplete.");
                deleteFile(path);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            response.close();
        }


        System.out.println("Saving update file to \"" + path + "\"");

        System.out.println("Update file saved.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to download update file.");
        ex.printStackTrace();

        deleteFile(path);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Server:**

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Received file download request.");

    String requestMethod = httpExchange.getRequestMethod();

    if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
    {
        Path path = Paths.get("ism","download", FILENAME);

        if (Files.exists(path))
        {
            long size = Files.size(path);

            Headers responseHeaders = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
            responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/x-7z-compressed");
            responseHeaders.set("Content-Length", "" + size);
            responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+ FILENAME + "\"");
            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, size);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
            Files.copy(path, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();

            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " File downloaded - " + size + " bytes total.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " File does not exist.");

            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
            httpExchange.getResponseBody().close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Method not supported.");

        Headers responseHeaders = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(405, 0);
        httpExchange.getResponseBody().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Client code looks fine. You need to collect memory dump when it fails ans analyze it with MAT or other similar tool.

Comment: It sounds like you're downloading the entire file to memory and then writing it to disk, instead of writing it as you receive it.

Comment: You should also take a look at your `entity != null` check, since you call `entity.getContentLength` before the check, meaning it would have already thrown a NullPointerException when you reach the check if it was null.

Comment: @AliceRyhl yea, thank you for noticing.

Comment: @AliceRyhl And how do I avoid downloading the entire file to memory? Read to byte buffer -> write buffer to file -> flush?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HttpEntity and the other spring framework stuff, but if you can get an input stream and copy 1024 bytes each iteration, while writing them to the output stream as you read them, it should work. To be honest, I'd expect `entity.writeTo(fileOutputStream);` to do this already, but if you get errors I guess it's buffering them.

Comment: Alice Ryhl, it's not "Spring Framework", it's "Apache HttpComponents" and yea, I also expect to `entity.writeTo` to do this already.